# Does drupal have another module that have the same feature as media watermark?

Tags: media

[image]

I am looking a watermark module that have a selection watermark just like in the image.

Unfortunately the [media watermark](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_watermark) module is support drupal 7.

Does drupal have another module that have the same feature as media watermark?

PS: I am using drupal 6.

Comment: I wish I find the alternative for Drupal 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [ImageCache Actions](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions) Module. I think this will help you...